# "uncaught throw :warden" when testing redirects for users not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, warden

This is a spec for a very typical controller with a `before_filter` which redirects to login page when a not-logged-in user (a.k.a. a *guest*) tries to access `/projects/new`.

```rb
describe ProjectsController do
  (...)

  describe "GET new" do
    context 'when not logged in' do
      before { sign_in_nobody }

      context 'creating project' do
        before { get :new }

        it 'denies access' do
          expect(response).to be_redirect
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I have specced all possible outcomes of accessing `:index`, `:show` and `:new` for *guests*, *users*, *admins* and *superadmins*. I didn't have any problems using neither logged or guest users, admins or not – but this is actually the first time this spec touched an action that involves Devise's `before_filter :autheticate_user!` and it fails miserably at that.

As you might already suspect – the spec doesn't even reach `expect(response).to be_redirect`, it throws a hissy fit before:

```
Failures:

1) ProjectsController GET new when not logged in creating project denies access
   Failure/Error: get :new
   ArgumentError:
     uncaught throw :warden
   # ./spec/controllers/projects_controller_spec.rb:344:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've searched for an answer to question: "how to properly test for unauthenticated (*guest*) users with rspec and devise", but everyone only talks about having problem with actually logging users in devise for RSpec to use.
A problem which I solved thusly:

```rb
#spec/support/devise_authenticators.rb
include Devise::TestHelpers

def sign_in_nobody
  @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  sign_in User.new
end

def sign_in_user
  @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
  sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end
```

However it's not the logging in that fails here, it's the "being not logged".
So far I got absolutely nothing and I know people **HAVE** to test those scenarios somehow.

Right now I'm using a walkaround:

```rb
before { sign_in_nobody }

context 'creating project' do
  it 'denies access' do
    expect{ get :new }.to raise_exception("uncaught throw :warden")
  end
end
```

But even tho it's practically correct (`uncaught throw :warden` happens only when `authenticate_user!` fails so it can be used as an expectation) in theory it feels really dirty.

Any ideas how to do it properly?

(...Maybe I shouldn't be testing this at all, seeing as how the correctness of `before_filter authenticate_user!` is Devise's responsibility not mine?)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [SO11152671](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152671/devise-warden-error-thrown-for-authenticate-user-in-functional-rails-test#answer-20725510). I've pasted a full answer there. In short, you'll need to add includes for the Devise test helper and the Warden test helper both in the actual ControllerTest class and not in test_helper.rb.

Answer (score 4):

It *should* just work. I just spent a while fixing the same problem, and it turned out we had a test helper that overrides `process` for controller tests. Devise also overrides it to `catch :warden` so I just needed to `include Devise::TestHelpers` before including the default params module.

For an example of what I'm talking about when I say we overrode `process`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022839/set-rspec-default-get-request-format-to-json/14623960#14623960) which describes how to set default params to include `format: json`

Comment: I have the same error, but I don't understand where should I insert `include Devise::TestHelpers`. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: You can do it in your test class or in the helper for all controllers. For example, see the top 2 headings on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-tests-with-Rails-3-(and-rspec) for Test::Unit and RSpec.

Comment: Thank you! I was having this problem where the `uncaught throw :warden` error was being raised, even though we had the proper test helpers included. Turned out we had a `default_params` helper just like the one you linked to, which was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

So the lesson is that `uncaught throw :warden` happens when `authenticate_user!` fails.

So figure out why your the user's authentication is a failing, and you'll have solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I solved it like this:

```
e = catch(:warden) { get root_url }
expect(e[:message]).to be(:not_activated)
```