# Devise and Rspec - error in controller test when testing redirect for unauthenticated users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I'm trying to write a test that makes sure unauthenticated useres are not able to access a certain page. Here is my spec

```
   it "redirects to the sign in page for unauthenticated users" do
      bob = Fabricate(:user)
      sign_out bob
      carolina_skiff = Fabricate(:boat_brand)
      get :edit, id: carolina_skiff.id
      expect(response).to redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
```

When I run this I get this error.

```
Failure/Error: get :edit, id: carolina_skiff.id
     ArgumentError:
       uncaught throw :warden
```

It seems like I'm not able to log out a user. I have another spec where I'm signing in a user and that one works fine.

```
   it "sets the @boat_brand" do
      bob = Fabricate(:user)
      sign_in bob
      carolina_skiff = Fabricate(:boat_brand)
      get :edit, id: carolina_skiff.id
      expect(assigns(:boat_brand)).to eq(carolina_skiff)
    end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where does the `sign_out` method come from?

Comment: It's a test helper method provided by Devise https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#test-helpers

Comment: You're creating a user, then trying to sign them out before you sign them in.  OR... Maybe you are trying to do this with an unauthenticated user and it should throw an error?  Or at least have a notice?

Comment: If I take out the user and sign_out user my test says `Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200>` . it seems like devise is doing something in the background that i can't test.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152671/devise-warden-error-thrown-for-authenticate-user-in-functional-rails-test#answer-20725510

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help, but I came across similar problem when trying to do functional tests of devise redirection after log in. These are important points:

1. Test exactly `Devise::SessionsController` (not eg. UsersController) or write `test Devise::SessionsController`
2. Force correct mapping as described in docs: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)
3. include Devise::TestHelpers

Sample test with redirection can look like this:

```
require "test_helper"

describe 'Devise::SessionsControllerTest' do
  # If you want different name in describe block write:
  # tests Devise::SessionsController

  include Devise::TestHelpers

  test "should redirect to page_x after logged in" do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    user = users :user
    sign_in user
    get :new
    assert_redirected_to orders_path
  end
end
```

Where `:user` is just regular valid devise user, and `orders_path` is expected redirect path after log in. This is not exact log in test but rather test of the redirection from login page for logged in user (to be precise).